# Alternative text for <span> element styled as icon to meet accessibility guidelines

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag

I've been asked to look for areas of our site which do not meet accessibility guidelines.  I'm currently looking into whether all icons we use that have semantic meaning have alternative text, in order to meet WCAG 2.1 1.1.1.

In one place we use a `<span>` element to represent a Low, Medium or High status.  This is styled as an icon - just a coloured background and surrounding box with the letter L in the centre.  HTML is

```
<span class="icon" title="Low" role="img">L</span>
```

Given the title and the inner text "L", is this sufficient to meet the guideline?  If not, what should be added?

Comment: added an extra bit of info for you that I missed the first time I read the question / answered, apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than thinking about meeting guidelines (I can't think of a specific one you would "fail" though just so you are aware) just think what makes the site easier to use / provides the best possible experience.

As we can't see the surrounding items we can't comment on whether an "L" makes sense in context.

As such the simplest thing would be to add an `aria-label` to the span. This will mean that a screen reader will actually read "low" rather than "l".

```
<span class="icon" title="Low" role="img" aria-label="low">L</span>
```

You may also want to say what item is "low" as part of the label if this span isn't part of a paragraph. `aria-label="widget one stock is low"`.

As [`title` is not very reliable for screen readers](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/attributes/#title) (and useless for people on touch devices) you might also consider having a key for sighted users that explains what L, M, H etc. mean (or whatever letters you use) and then you can do away with the `title`.

This will also greatly benefit mobile users (if the site is mobile friendly) who can't see the `title` attribute.

### One adjustment

I realised after the answer was accepted I didn't cover the `role="image"` part.

That is probably not needed at all once you have the `aria-label` on it, especially if you use the longer form of the label `aria-label="widget one stock is low"` I suggested.

Yet again depends on your use case but I would be 80% confident in saying this is the case without seeing anything else.

This will also probably help when running automated accessibility tests as it won't complain about a missing `alt` attribute.

So

`<span class="icon" aria-label="widget one stock is low">L</span>` would be perfectly valid.

Comment: But isn't `aria-label` meant for interactive elements only?

Comment: That is a bit of a myth / nuance of inconsistent implementation. Going by the standards you can add `aria-label` to nearly any HTML element. https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#aria-label - but there is a bit of inconsistent behaviour in older browser / screen reader combinations https://www.tpgi.com/short-note-on-aria-label-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby/ - but I believe you should work to standards and spec wherever possible as a11y is complicated enough!